# How does the code 'printf("%d %d %d\n",(a,b,c));' work?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int a=3, b=4, c=5;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", (a, b, c));
}
```

And the result is:

```
5 2280760 2281472
```

What is the explanation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have caused an undefined behavior:

This - `(a,b,c)` is evaluated as the last parameter, e.g. `c`, so the first printed number is 5 (`c = 5`) the other two are uninitialized parameters.

Comment: yeah,I know this ,but just wonder about first evaluated as c,the rest of the params doesn't assign,why not raise an error in compiling and print unexpected result?

Comment: @Crystal Cat: Variadic functions (i.e. functions with variable number of parameters, like `printf`) cannot be generally checked at compile time. The compiler simply does not know how many parameters the function expects. However, some compilers (like GCC) can do some limited checks for standard functions (like `printf`) and issue warnings if something is wrong. They are still not allowed to reject the code though, since technically the code is compilable, it just doesn't work in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work. It produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You supplied three format specifiers to `printf` and provided only one variadic argument, since in C `(a,b,c)` is an expression that evaluates to the value of `c` (read about the *[comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)*).

Since the number of arguments does not match the number of format specifiers, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Crystal Cat: No, it produces *undefined behavior*, which just happens to randomly include "printing var 'c'" into the wild mix of things that happen or can potentially happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two arguments to your `printf` call: `"%d %d %d"` and the result of evaluating `(a,b,c)`.

The result of `(a,b,c)` is just the last item in the list: `c`, which is 5. That's passed to printf, which displays `5` for the first %d.

Since there are no more arguments, the remaining %d's just display whatever garbage is sitting on the call stack, resulting in the strange values you see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing about  comma expression,comma expression contains two operands of any type separated by a comma and has **left-to-right** associativity. The left operand is fully evaluated, possibly producing side effects, and its value, if there is one, is discarded. The right operand is then evaluated. The type and value of the result of a comma expression are those of its right operand, after the usual unary conversions.

The result of a comma expression is not an lvalue.

so you getting the above result

As IBM states in [their documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/language_ref/co.html):

> The primary use of the comma operator is to produce side effects in
>   the following situations:
>
> 1. Calling a function
> 2. Entering or repeating
>      an iteration loop
> 3. Testing a condition
> 4. Other situations where a side effect is required but the result of the expression is not immediately needed

Answer (score 0):

[MByD said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025081/how-does-the-code-printfd-d-d-n-a-b-c-work/12025097#12025097):

> This - (a,b,c) is evaluated as the last parameter, e.g. c, so the first printed number is 5 (c = 5) the other two are uninitialized parameters.

But a and b are not uninitialized (try the code below):

```
int a=3,b=4,c=5;
printf("%d %d %d\n",a,(a,b,c),b);
```

due to the bracket, it is assumed as one parameter, and due to parsing from **left to right** (as user null pointer said) it found c to be its value.

The above code outputs `3 5 4`.